# Why WebBrowser control has this strange behavior?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a form with a `webbrowser`. Events: `Navigating`, `Navigated` and `DocumentCompleted` are attached.

This is what I am getting after telling it  `.Navigate(new Url("http://google.com"));`

```
20:42:42:036: 1. Navigating to: http://google.com/
20:42:42:545: 2. Navigated: http://www.google.com/
20:42:42:854: 3. Navigating to: about:blank
20:42:43:002: 4. Navigated: about:blank
20:42:43:004: 5. Loaded: about:blank
20:42:43:158: 6. Loaded: http://www.google.com/
```

Can somebody explain why I am getting this `about:blank` stuff?

The code is just displaying the `e.Url` parameter of each event handler.

Comment: Use of `about:blank` could mean a lot of things. Does this happen if you navigate to another site besides google? What version of IE is on the system?

Comment: My guess is that google uses iframes or object tags which fire the navigated event.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the automatic navigation to about:blank is a known "security blanket" of sorts used by the `WebBrowser` object to ensure the HTML object is valid before trying to load the page you request, as explained in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa752047.aspx):

> [...] the IWebBrowser2::Navigate2 method is used to navigate to the about:blank page. Navigating to this empty page ensures that MSHTML is loaded and that the HTML elements are available through the Dynamic HTML (DHTML) Object Model.

Also, the `DocumentCompleted` event should work. Are you sure your events aren't doing anything else?

I've tried this simple code, and it works as expected:

```
namespace CSharpWindowsPractice
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add("Navigated to: " + e.Url);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add("Navigating to: " + e.Url);
        }

        private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add("DocumentCompleted: " + e.Url);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(@"http://google.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

After pushing the button, you get the following:

[image]